# Evaluating JavaScript into WKWebView to fetch the Video URL doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, url, wkwebview

So I'm trying to get the video source URL by evaluating javascript into `WKWebView`. Tried to search through many different posts but none of them got me what I want. I'm trying to download videos from Dailymotion.com , which I've opened in my `WKWebView`. Now in my WKWebView's delegate methods I am passing the current URL of Webview for evaluation of JavaScript so that I get the video URL.

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)
    {
        print("wkwebview")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)
    {
        print("wkwebview")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        //print("wkwebview")
        //print(navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString as Any)


        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('video')")
        {
            (result, error) in
            guard error == nil else
            {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
             print(String(describing: result))
        }



       //loadURL(site: (webView.url?.absoluteString)!)

        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

The error I've been getting is `Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=5 "JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type}`

Answer (score 0):

Swift can't interpret javascript objects - in this case you're returning an array of element objects with the tag 'video'.

However, Swift can receive String values fine. Assuming your video element has the url as a 'src' attribute, you can just use `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].getAttribute('src')` in place of your current JS call to get the source url as a string.

`.getElementsByTagName` returns an array. You'll need to grab the right index if you have multiple video elements, or just grab the first (like I did above).

Alternatively:
`document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].src`